# Share an active IO::Socket::SSL socket across Perl threads

Tags: multithreading, perl, sockets, ssl

I wish to share/pass an `IO::Socket::SSL` object across Perl threads (5.10.1 & up).

I accept an SSL connection in one thread - it's already open and talking SSL - then hand it off to other already running worker threads.  The `IO::Socket::SSL` object isn't shareable because it's based upon a symbol/glob; `shared_clone()` etc. fail.

I thought to grab the SSL context and the fileno, which are shareable, then use `new_from_fd()` to recreate the socket in the worker threads.    For example, the listener would do (error checking, etc omitted for simplicity here):

```
...
my $sock = $listener->accept();             # Grab the next SSL connection
$sock->peek(...);                           # Peek to see what to do with it...
my $ssl  = $sock->_get_ssl_object();        # Get internal SSL handle
my $ctx  = Net::SSLeay::get_SSL_CTX($ssl);  # Get context
...
```

The above gets me the context, which looks to be just a scalar number.  In the worker threads, I take this context and the fileno, and do:

```
my $reborn = IO::Socket::SSL->new_from_fd ($fd,
    PeerAddr      => $ADDR,
    Blocking      => 0,
    ...other non-SSL options...
    SSL_reuse_ctx => $ctx,
);
```

I've also tried just `IO::Socket::SSL->new()`, and variations of `fdopen()` and `open()`.  They blow-up within the `SSL.pm` module (line 1343, the `isa` call) in a way that indicates the context value should be an `IO::Socket::SSL` or `IO::Socket::SSL::SSL_Context` object.

I have not found an incantation that works.  How can I get a valid context object to pass to `IO::Socket::SSL->new_from_fd()` so that I can re-instantiate the original socket in the new thread?  And, would this even work?  Ideas?

Comment: Update:  Grrrr...  I'm done beating my head against this wall who's name is "Perl threads".  I reworked my whole code base to be a select()-based model instead, and I'm movin' on...  ;-(   I wish the Perl gods had chose a pthreads-like model instead!